# Find base of numbers in a sum?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, computer-science

is there an easier way to find the base A in the following without essentially brute-forcing it with different conversions until I get the result?

Again, trying to find base A such that the following addition works.

$$ 24)_{A} + 17)_{A} = 40)_{A} $$

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert everything to base $10$:
\begin{align*}
(2A + 4) + (1A + 7) &= (4A + 0) \\
3A + 11 &= 4A \\
A &= 11
\end{align*}

Comment: So would the same apply for division? i.e.
$$ 14)_{A} / 2)_{A} = 5)_{A} $$
Where the base would be 2?

Comment: Using the same approach, we get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1A + 4}{2} &= 5 \\
A + 4 &= 10 \\
A &= 6
\end{align*}